# Convert JSON file to CSV using Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
    "resultSet": {
        "totalRecords": "2",
        "agentLogins": [
            {
                "phoneNumber": "99999",
                "callerId": "999999999",
                "stationId": "99999999",
                "stationName": "",
                "loginDate": "2020-09-17T15:25:34.410Z"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "99999",
                "callerId": "99999999",
                "stationId": "999999",
                "stationName": "",
                "loginDate": "2020-09-17T17:22:48.613Z"
            }
           
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying convert it to a CSV file with Python, here is my code:

```
import json 
import csv 
  
with open('agentLogins.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
  
agentLogins = data['agentLogins']
  
data_file = open('agentLogins.csv', 'w') 
  
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file) 
  
count = 0
  
for emp in agentLogins: 
    if count == 0: 
  
        header = emp.keys() 
        csv_writer.writerow(header) 
        count += 1
  
    csv_writer.writerow(emp.values()) 
  
data_file.close()


I am getting an error: agentLogins = data['agentLogins'] KeyError: 'agentLogins:'.

If I Remove the first part it works:
    "resultSet": {
        "totalRecords": "2",
```

I am just wondering if I can get it too work without removing anything.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to format it properly.

Comment: Your JSON does not contain an item called `agentLogins`.  Why would you expect to find it?

Comment: Try `agentLogins = data[‘resultSet’][‘agentLogins’]`

Answer (score 0):

convert `data['agentLogins']` to `data['resultSet']['agentLogins']` and it will work, this is the solution :

```
# Opening JSON file and loading the data  into the variable data 
with open('/content/jsonFile.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
  
agentLogins  =  data['resultSet']['agentLogins']
# now we will open a file for writing 
data_file = open('agentLogins.csv', 'w') 
  
# create the csv writer object 
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file) 


# Counter variable used for writing  
# headers to the CSV file 
count = 0
  
for emp in agentLogins: 
    if count == 0: 
  
        # Writing headers of CSV file 
        header = emp.keys() 
        csv_writer.writerow(header) 
        count += 1
  
    # Writing data of CSV file 
    csv_writer.writerow(emp.values()) 
  
data_file.close()
```